# Why is Mule Enterprise Standalone on Mac not responding on port 8585

Tags: mule

I just downloaded and launched Mule Enterprise Standalone 3.4.0 trial for my Mac.
Everything looks fine in the logs, but when I try to launch the Mule Management Console from my browser at localhost:8585/mmc I am getting a 404 NOT_FOUND error.

I thought perhaps 8585 was busy but an lsof -i :8585 showed that nothing was running on that port before I ran Mule. Once I start Mule I see "TCP *:8585 (LISTEN)"; so I know something is listening on 8585!

So why can't I bring up the management console????

Comment: Do you have the mmc application listed in the logs?

Comment: Yes* mmc        * DEPLOYED
  * default    * DEPLOYED

Comment: Is your machine's name "localhost"? You might have hit this: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.4.0+Release+Notes#MuleESB3.4.0ReleaseNotes-localhostBehavior<br>
Try the suggested solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. For posterity, this is what I did:
System preferences/Sharing/WebSharing.
Look at the machine name specified under your Your computer's Website is available at this address: <xyz>
Now go to http://xyz:8585/mmc (where xyz is the computer name listed or you assigned there)

Comment: (This is why link-only answers aren't really an SO thing.)